# How can I loop through a collection in the index file?

Tags: craft3, entries

I am basically wondering where does this `section('services')` is set up and how. https://github.com/craftcms/demo/blob/3f224f1f2e260c3e18190b16420c2e661cbb35ee/templates/services/_entry.html#L22

I need to loop through the collection entries on the `_index.html` to display a small card for each one, but I don't know how to reach them from the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set up a section (or check the one you are referring to), in your control panel, go to **Settings** then **Sections**.

To loop through entries on a template, for this service section for example, you do:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('services').all() %}
    {{ entry.title }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Yes, I was confused if the section was an html section or a Craft section so this cleared things up. Thanks!